# Magento: Category Lock/Warning or T&C

Tags: magento

I wonder if there is a way to add a Warning/Advisory or Terms & Conditions (preferably) to a category or a landing page to warn users about adult content. On the shop I'm working on there is an "Adult Section" Category for Erotic Toys, Lingerie, cosplay, etc. and I need to warn users about such content before they access the section in case they're less than 18.

I've searched the web and only found paid extensions which I cannot afford. Does anyone know how to do this?

I'm using Magento CE 1.7.

Thanks,

EDIT:

Ok, so I've been trying to figure out how to do this and I just figured that the best way to do it would be to just create a Category Landing Page and adding a java script for T&C redirect to the page I want it to.

This is the code I would use for the Category Landing Page with blank content would be this.

```
<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>
<?php $_collectionSize = $_categories->count() ?>

<div>
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
<?php
$layer = Mage::getSingleton(‘catalog/layer’);
$layer->setCurrentCategory(Mage::getModel(‘catalog/category’)->load($_category->getId()));
$helper = Mage::helper(‘catalog/category’);
?>
```

Then I found a code snippet that would redirect the user to a page of my liking after clicking accept but I'm not sure how to implement it and/or if this is the best choice. Here's the code.

```
<form action="url-to-go-to" method="GET" onsubmit="return checkCheckBox(this)">
I accept: <input type="checkbox" value="0" name="agree">
<input type="submit" value="Continue">
<input type="button" value="Exit" onclick="document.location.href='BACKTOWHAT.html';">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function checkCheckBox(f){
if (f.agree.checked == false )
{
alert("Please tick the box to continue");
return false;
} else
return true;
}
-->
</script>
```

Now I was thinking that it would be best to just create a simple CMS page and point the category on the top menu to that page and once they have agreed and clicked on continue, they could be taken to the actual category by simply pointing the 'onclick' to the URL of the actual category.

Not sure if this is the best way but it's the only way I could come up. The other way I thought of would've required me to take the "agreements" during checkout that already comes with magento and make an extension that would allow me to place it on any page and call the "Agreement ID" from the Sales/Terms and Conditions tab but I don't know how to actually do that, it was just a thought.

If anyone has a better solution, I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

I would add some sort of JavaScript that shows a div over the top of the whole page, that will create a session cookie when you accept to watch the category. Otherwise, make a back() in the history navigation. This way you don't need another page, just JS.

On another note, could you please post the extensions you found that do this?